# MySQL query to select specific data range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a huge database in MySQL, one of the columns contains a serial number (in my table i have about 17,000 serial numbers), i want to select a specific serial number and to display all the columns of this number and of the 50 serial numbers before it, how can i do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are the serial numbers sequential, or are some numbers skipped? Can you show the table schema? Is the serial number the primary key for the table?

Comment: Is the serial number unique in the table?  Are you looking for 51 rows or for all the rows associated with 51 serial numbers?

Comment: Some numbers are skipped, the primary key is different for every serial number, i have two data from the same serial number but with different primary key

Answer (score 2):

I think you want it like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE serialnumber<=@yourserialnumberwhichyousearch
ORDER BY serialnumber DESC
LIMIT 51;
```

Comment: This only works in POSTGRES as far as I know, MYSQL is LIMIT 0,50

Comment: Thanks! I think now its right. Could you check the query again. It should contain 51 Elements, because this specific element is asked (1 Element) and 50 Elements before.

Answer (score 0):

You don't state that the serial number is unique.  If not, then a `join` is one method:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select t.*
      from t
      where t.serialnumber < @sn
      order by t.serialnumber desc
      limit 50
     ) t50
     on t.serialnumber = @sn or t.serialnumber = t50
```

Note that this will return 50 serial numbers if your given number is not in the data.